# How did the Romans build straight roads that stretched very long distances?

Tags: roman-empire, transportation

I once read that the Romans were masters of building roads that stretched long distances in a straight line like the [Fosse Way road](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fosse_Way) in Britain.

I never thought much of it until I watched [Canada & The United States: Bizarre Borders Part 2](http://youtu.be/qMkYlIA7mgw) where the person mentions that the border is `about as straight as a pre-GPS civilization could make`, and as someone who has never attempted to draw a straight line over a long distance, I never thought of all of the problems that you would run into.

**How did the Romans build straight roads that stretched very long distances?**

Comment: No idea on the how, but at some point they realized that their obsession with straight roads was counterproductive. Going straight up and down a hill, or building a bridge over every little river or pond you may find in your way isn't either the smartest thing to do, nor the more cost effective.

Comment: @YannisRizos Yes, I also read about that. The idea was that you build the road once and use it a million times so having it straight means less travel for the user than having him go around it which they thought would save them resource and time in the long run.

Comment: Important in having straight roads is the desire and willingness to have them. Straightness demands hill leveling and valley filling or bridging which is far more expensive than following contours. || The biblical "every valley shall be filled and every hill ..." is an allusion to roads made then for kings to travel on - again, an expensive prestige exercise. || On a London-Bangkok flight we flew over India and I took photos from ~= 35,000 feet. I showed a photo to a cousin who said, not knowing the location, "Those roads are originally British or Roman". I asked why. "They're straight".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simple answer is that they used a form of surveying tool called a [groma](http://www.historylearningsite.co.uk/roman_roads.htm). This basically consisted of two pieces of wood nailed together to form a square cross with right angles in all corners. Each piece of wood had lead weights attached to the end, and they determined they had a straight line when the lead weight from one piece of wood lined up with the one in front of it. Wood posts would be used to stake out the boundaries of the road in order to help maintain a straight line over an extended distance.

As an interesting side note, I found [another source](http://www.crystalinks.com/romeroads.html) that indicated that Roman soldiers carried a tool such as a hatchet, pick, or spade in addition to his more traditional gear. When there was a need to build roads, the engineers would take groups of soldiers to use as laborers. This served a dual purpose of keeping the men in shape while also keeping them out of trouble.

Comment: They weren't called *Marius's Mules* for no reason. Caesar could as easily have echoed Erwin Rommel, from *Infantry Attack*: "Even on the attack I found the spade the equal of the rifle."

Comment: The same surveyors and tools were used to lay out the camps and forts, which followed a standardized plan.

Answer (score -2):

Here is an interesting and well-cited article from Ferris State University College of Technology Surveying Engineering (there's a name that flows from the tongue) covering the technical aspects of [ancient Roman surveying techniques](http://www.surveyhistory.org/ferris_state_university1.htm).

Comment: Link-only answers are susceptible to link-rot, which renders them useless. Also, some people prefer not to click links to external sites. Please paraphrase/quote the article  (or relevant) portions in this answer. As it stands now, this answer in itself does not answer the question at all.

Comment: @Luke - Baloney. I've had accepted answers in this format before. It is a broad field to cover, and a waste of time to plagiarize an excellent and succinct source in its entirety. Is this a new guideline? Where is it documented?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92505/192187 for example. The policy has been in place for quite a while.

Comment: +1 to counter the downvote. Risk of link rot is just a fact of life that we all learn to live with, it applies every time one cites a reference. I might not have upvoted this answer but putting it into minus territory seems wrong to me.

Comment: Yes, but paraphrasing or quoting relevant portions here would solve that.

Comment: @Luke Interesting link to MSO that you gave there. The [second-highest voted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92507/181225) there is quite reasonable, in my opinion. In brief, first drop a friendly (!) comment prodding the Answerer to add some content. When you critique _and_ downvote in one fell swoop, it gets people's backs up, especially if yours is the first vote.

Comment: @RISwampYankee (and everyone else): This would be best discussed on Meta. While the general policy is that link only answers are not preferable, there's no reason why we can't establish our own policy on History (although, chances are we'll end up with more or less the same policy).

Comment: @YannisRizos I hesitate to be the one to start a Meta thread ;) Yes, I would agree that "link only answers are not preferable". Nor was I asking for a policy unique to History.SE. But even a naked link to a useful web page can be more helpful than no information at all. So taking that into account and human dynamics being what they are, I am suggesting that an immediate downvote accompanied by a comment quoting SE policy may be less productive than the conciliatory approach suggested in that answer on MSO that I linked to. That's all, for my part. I will shut up now :)

Comment: In fact, now that this Answer is at +2 votes, I should downvote it! Just kidding, @RISwampYankee (I think...)

Comment: Not only is this a link-only answer, the linked page does not answer the question.